# Designing battery low indicator for a 3.7 V Li-Ion battery

Tags: voltage, power, current, indicator, cell

I am looking for a solution to create an indicator for a li-ion 3.7 V single cell lighting red if the voltage of the cell is ≤ 3.3 V. SG3546 was an ideal option, but it looks that this chip is not available these days.

Is there any other option or circuit with low current consumption?

Comment: I see that you commented on this question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/241210/simplest-battery-low-indicator-for-a-3-7-volt-lithium-ion-battery?rq=1 What is wrong with the accepted answer given there?

Comment: If you want to light a red led if your Li cell is less than 3v3 you should consider the draw of the led which will be more than the chip .Consider something based on a band gap reference ,Think about how long the red led will run for before the cell gets to 3V .At 3V you should shut down all current draw .Fleshing the Led will reduce average current draw.

Answer (score 2):

The Microsemi chip is a voltage supervisor device.

One thought would be to replace it with another voltage supervisor, with a similar threshold, that's actually available. The MAX6463UR30 seems pretty darn close, with a 3.0V threshold. There are others - I show 100+ for 3V at Mouser, from various vendors.